# Change numbering of equations in LyX

Tags: equations, numbering, lyx

I have just tried to use LyX, but I get some trouble when I numbered equations.

For example: when I number my equation, on screen appear like this:

```
            a=b   (0.1)
```

How can I drop number 0 so that it displays like this:

```
            a=b    (1)
```

Answer (score 5):

You may have switched around some document classes that added a specific numbering module which updates this numbering.

Under Document > Settings... > Modules, remove (or delete) the Number Equations by Section module:

[image]

Alternatively, if this fails, you can add the following Document > Settings... > Local Layout:

```
Format 60

Requires amsmath

AddToPreamble
  \numberwithout{equation}{section}
EndPreamble

Counter equation
  Within      "none"
  LabelString "\arabic{equation}"
End
```

Comment: @BinhNguyen: If this answer solved your problem, consider accepting it as such. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/5764)